# WooCommerce 404?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Hello dear programmers

Every time I update or install a plugin in my wordpress website it gives a 404 error

But even if I don't update anything every day or every 2/3 days it is giving an error

I deactivate and then activate the woocommerce plugin, the website starts working fine

What can cause the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to delete htaccess file and save permalinks